# angular js array in model

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I am repeating a form using ng-repeat. the repetition is to create a new form.
I want to submit all forms data on single click. i am not able to find how I can assign multiple values in array.

Here is my form:

```
<div id="check" ng-repeat="screen in screens">
                   <input type="hidden" name="scrnid" ng-model="screen.scrnid" value="{{ screen.scrnid }}" />
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="screen.bdayname" placeholder="Name" ng-required/>
            <label>Date:</label>
            <input type="date" ng-model="screen.bdaydate" placeholder="Date" ng-required/>
            <br/>
               </div>

               <button class="btn" type="submit" ng-click="newBirthday()">Save</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
        <input type="button" class="btn" ng-click="createScreen()" /><i class="icon-plus"></i>Add
</div>
```

and it is my controller

```
app.controller('main', function($scope){ 

    $scope.screens = [{scrnid: "1"}];
    $scope.scrnid = 1;
    $scope.createScreen = function()
    {
            $scope.screens.push({scrnid: "" + ($scope.screens.length + 1)});            
    };

    $scope.bdays = [];        
    // Create the function to push the data into the "bdays" array

    $scope.newBirthday = function(){        

        $scope.bdays.push($scope.screens.length);  // how to push mutiple records in array dynamically

        $scope.screen.bdayname = '';
        $scope.screen.bdaydate = '';
    };
});
```

help will be appreciated...

Comment: `assign multiple values in array`, what are these multiple values?

Comment: $scope.bdays.push()  

here in this array if i want to send multiple values i will do it like this:
$scope.bdays.push([
{'name': 'name1'},
{'name': 'name2'}
]);

this is angularjs way to do.  But what should i do to insert the values from my html form that is repeated,  into this array...

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the code to get the objects to be stored into the bday scope variable

```
var app=angular.module("birthdayToDo",[]);


app.controller('main', function($scope){ 

   $scope.screens = [{scrnid: "1"}];
  $scope.scrnid = 1;
    $scope.createScreen = function(){
            $scope.screens.push({scrnid: "" + ($scope.screens.length + 1)});  

            console.log($scope.screens);          
        };

        $scope.bdays = [];        


    $scope.newBirthday = function(){

        for(i=0;i<$scope.screens.length;i++){
            $scope.bdays.push($scope.screens[i])
        }
        console.log($scope.bdays);


    };


    $scope.remove=function(item){ 
      var index=$scope.bdays.indexOf(item)
      $scope.bdays.splice(index,1);     
    }



});
```

Comment: Here you have done it for single form .

To pass single form values i can pass them easily. But if you have noticed i am repeating this form and now i want to submit all forms data .

how will i manage it with form repetition...

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9fqfh8ty/ here multiple forms are being used and a save action for each form, I have also editted the answer above , let me know if this solves your issue

Comment: Here you have three forms with three buttons setting up the target buttons value to fill in array.
I want three forms with single buttons and adding all three records values in arrray.

do u have any idea for that...

Comment: you mean you have 3 forms but a single save button ?

Comment: yes and those three forms are created in ng-repeat means i am having single form which i am repeating n  have single save button i want to save these forms on single click to database, and repeating of forms is dynamic . forms can be 3 or 4 or 5 ....

Comment: can you upload you code into a fiddle so that I can play with

Comment: Here is the fiddle link for my code.

https://jsfiddle.net/trig_php/z1o9nvne/

i don't know why it's not working on fiddle bt if u will try on localhost u will see this working..

Comment: Hi I have used your code and created another working fiddle. Check this and let me know if this solves your issue https://jsfiddle.net/vvc15rxj/ I have also updated my answer above

Comment: but i am not getting values in bdays array in which values are pushed.

:(

Comment: when you click on save, check the console ... on click of save the bday array is being consoled

Comment: here on console bt i can not send it to my html in other edit form . 
how will i display all values there ...

Comment: trig_php  you can have the other edit form within another controller and share data across controllers via creating a factory

Comment: thank @melwyn pawar u resolved my issue .. i will find ways for the rest.
this is very helpful.  :)

Comment: can you please tick right the answer, it may help others also :)

Comment: i tried it already but my reputation score is less than 15 , i can not do that , will do later.

Comment: i worked on the above but what is done here is u are pushing the count of repeated screens into the bdays array , what will be the way to get all the values into this array from all forms.

now i am stuck with this........   plz help me out....